# How to get nested form data in express.js?

Tags: forms, node.js, express

In Rails, if you have a form with underscores, it will assume a nested layout structure in params:

```
<input type="text" name="person_first" />
<input type="text" name="person_last" />
```

On the server, you'll get:

```
params #=> { person: { first: "Tom", last: "Hanks" } }
```

When I'm using Express.js in node.js, bodyparser doesn't seem to do the same thing. Looking at the code for bodyparser, it just runs the JSON parser on it, resulting in:

```
params #=> { person_first: "Tom", person_last: "Hanks" } }
```

Is there some way I can get the nested form data, like in Rails, when I'm using Express? Is there a library that enables me to do this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you are using `express.bodyParser` you can use array notation to pass nested data.

Add `express.bodyParser` middleware before your controllers.

```
app.use(express.bodyParser());
```

Now you can use this notation in your html code:

```
<input type="text" name="person[first]" />
<input type="text" name="person[last]" />
```

or

```
<input type="text" name="person[name][first]" />
<input type="text" name="person[name][last]" />
```

### Update for Express 4

The key here is setting `extended: true`

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
```

Comment: can we have a dot notation for eg person.first or person.name.first. or is there a parser which would do that

Comment: Do we have nested attributes like this in Koa2 too?