# How to make form POST request having field values grouped?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I'm working on an **Express** application using **Jade**. It should have a questionnaire page that must be sumitted by the user. The questionnaire form have a dynamic number of fields (radios, and checkboxes) for the answers, which are rendered server side. The form also have a couple of hidden inputs holding other data. I need to find out a way of grouping the fields that are answers from those that are not. The object that is sent to the server in the POST body is something like this:

```
{ 
  question1: "foo",
  question2: "bar",
  other_data: "Spain",
  another_field: "345345345"
}
```

But I need it to be nested this way:

```
{ 
  answers: {
    question1: "foo",
    question2: "bar"
  },
  other_data: "Spain",
  another_field: "345345345"
}
```

Since there are many types of forms, each of them having different number of fields and different field names would be very convenient to iterate over the answer object to collect the answers.

Normally we do it this way:

```
input(type="checkbox", name="question1", value=...)
...
input(type="checkbox", name="question2", value=...)
...
```

In this case I want something like this:

```
input(type="checkbox", name="answers.question1", value=...)
...
input(type="checkbox", name="answers.question2", value=...)
...
```

Is there any HTML/javascript trick to make this? Or a better solution to be implemented server-side (i.e: an Express middleware, etc.)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13421701/438992

Comment: Yes [Dave](http://stackoverflow.com/users/438992/dave-newton), that might work for me, thanks.